# cant create google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a Google script file for web (Google site). Once the file is created and I write in it, the lines jump to the right and I can't edit it any more.

If I use another account there is no problem. Also I have Google account (no Google apps acc.)

Is there a limit on the amount of code I can write? Because I have few Google apps scripts file that I wrote in the past and they have same problem.

Does any one know what can be the probable or how can I found the problem?

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> Is there a limit of codes I can write?
> ```

No, but there is a limitation with amount of resources you can use. To find out your own limitations, you can can check https://code.google.com/apis/console.

Comment: hello,thank you but i dont see any limitaton that couse me the problem

Comment: do you have any other idea?

Comment: This might be a problem with your browser, what browser are you using?

Comment: i am using chrome, the problem is also with explorer and when i use differnt account there is no problem

Comment: hello,
i have some google site with script code writen.
recently i cant edit the script file from the google account

i can edit them if i change the google account to another account with permission to edit

what can be the problem with my account?